# Formating RIGHT JOIN query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, subquery

I have SQL query which works:

```
SELECT table1.bike_id 
FROM
    ( 
        SELECT bike_id 
        FROM `bike_filters`
        WHERE (`bike_category_id` in (416,11111)) 
    ) as table1
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT bike_id 
        FROM `bike_filters`
        WHERE (`bike_category_id` in (5555,779)) 
    ) as table2 ON table1.bike_id = table2.bike_id
GROUP BY bike_id
```

But I need to add more `RIGHT JOIN`s lines, maybe 5 or more. How to form the query in the right way? I'm searching in the same table, but joining several records in one query to get bike_id, which fits all conditions.

The purpose of this query is to get `bike_id`s, which has all parameters by the query - bike can have 20 filters, but if user searches by 5 and bike matches them, we get bike_id by this query.

Table Structure:

```
| id | bike_id | bike_category_id |
| 1  | 3       | 416              |
| 2  | 3       | 779              |
| 3  | 3       | 344              |
| 4  | 3       | 332              |
| 5  | 4       | 444              |
| 5  | 5       | 555              |
```

I need something like this, this one is incorrect:

```
SELECT table1.bike_id 
FROM
    ( 
        SELECT bike_id 
        FROM `bike_filters` 
        WHERE (`bike_category_id` IN (416,11111)) 
    ) AS table1
    RIGHT JOIN ( 
        SELECT bike_id 
        FROM `bike_filters` 
        WHERE (`bike_category_id` IN (5555,779)) 
    ) AS table2
    RIGHT JOIN ( 
        SELECT bike_id 
        FROM `bike_filters` 
        WHERE (`bike_category_id` IN (5555,344)) 
    ) AS table3
    RIGHT JOIN ( 
        SELECT bike_id 
        FROM `bike_filters` 
        WHERE (`bike_category_id` IN (5555,332)) 
    ) AS table4
GROUP BY bike_id
```

Comment: You say "but if user searches by 5 and bike matches them,we get bike_id by this query" .  Matches 1 of them or all 5?

Comment: @JimCastro matches all five!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation, and put all the conditions in the `HAVING` clause, as follows:

```
SELECT bike_id
FROM bike_filters
GROUP BY bike_id
HAVING
   MAX(bike_category_id in (416,11111)) = 1
   AND MAX(bike_category_id in (5555,779)) = 1
```

This will return all `bike_id`s that :

- have category `416` *or* `11111`
- *and* have category `5555` or `779`

You can extend the `HAVING` clause as per your requirements.